# Cohort Analysis in Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, analytics, google-analytics-api

I want to make my own cohorts in google analytics. Can i specify my own metrics in metrics list. Default metrics are  like :

- transactions
- transactions per user
- revenue
- revenue per user

If yes, how to do so? If no, then how to log data for these predefined metrics?

Answer (score 0):

Analytics Reporting API V4:

You can use the [Analytics Reporting API V4](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/advanced#cohorts) to construct cohort requests

For example:

```
POST https://analyticsreporting.googleapis.com/v4/reports:batchGet
{
  "reportRequests":
  [
    {
      "viewId": "XXXX",
      "dimensions":
      [
        {
          "name": "ga:cohort"
        },
        {
          "name": "ga:cohortNthDay"
        }
      ],
      "metrics":
      [
        {
          "expression": "ga:cohortActiveUsers"
        },
        {
           "expression": "ga:transactions"
        }
          ],
      "cohortGroup":
      {
        "cohorts":
        [
          {
            "name": "cohort 1",
            "type": "FIRST_VISIT_DATE",
            "dateRange":
            {
              "startDate": "2015-08-01",
              "endDate": "2015-08-01"
            }
          },
          {
            "name": "cohort 2",
            "type": "FIRST_VISIT_DATE",
            "dateRange":
            {
              "startDate": "2015-07-01",
              "endDate": "2015-07-01"
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

[See the API explorer for an example](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#search/analyticsreporting.reports.batchget/m/analyticsreporting/v4/analyticsreporting.reports.batchGet?_h=3&resource=%257B%250A++%2522reportRequests%2522%253A+%250A++%255B%250A++++%257B%250A++++++%2522viewId%2522%253A+%2522XXXX%2522%252C%250A++++++%2522dimensions%2522%253A+%250A++++++%255B%250A++++++++%257B%250A++++++++++%2522name%2522%253A+%2522ga%253Acohort%2522%250A++++++++%257D%252C%250A++++++++%257B%250A++++++++++%2522name%2522%253A+%2522ga%253AcohortNthDay%2522%250A++++++++%257D%250A++++++%255D%252C%250A++++++%2522metrics%2522%253A+%250A++++++%255B%250A++++++++%257B%250A++++++++++%2522expression%2522%253A+%2522ga%253AcohortActiveUsers%2522%250A++++++++%257D%252C%250A++++++++%257B%250A++++++++++%2522expression%2522%253A+%2522ga%253Atransactions%2522%250A++++++++%257D%250A++++++%255D%252C%250A++++++%2522cohortGroup%2522%253A+%250A++++++%257B%250A++++++++%2522cohorts%2522%253A+%250A++++++++%255B%250A++++++++++%257B%250A++++++++++++%2522name%2522%253A+%2522cohort+1%2522%252C%250A++++++++++++%2522type%2522%253A+%2522FIRST_VISIT_DATE%2522%252C%250A++++++++++++%2522dateRange%2522%253A+%250A++++++++++++%257B%250A++++++++++++++%2522startDate%2522%253A+%25222015-08-01%2522%252C%250A++++++++++++++%2522endDate%2522%253A+%25222015-08-01%2522%250A++++++++++++%257D%250A++++++++++%257D%252C%250A++++++++++%257B%250A++++++++++++%2522name%2522%253A+%2522cohort+2%2522%252C%250A++++++++++++%2522type%2522%253A+%2522FIRST_VISIT_DATE%2522%252C%250A++++++++++++%2522dateRange%2522%253A+%250A++++++++++++%257B%250A++++++++++++++%2522startDate%2522%253A+%25222015-07-01%2522%252C%250A++++++++++++++%2522endDate%2522%253A+%25222015-07-01%2522%250A++++++++++++%257D%250A++++++++++%257D%250A++++++++%255D%250A++++++%257D%250A++++%257D%250A++%255D%250A%257D&).

Not all dimensions and metrics can be queried together. For example you will not be able to query for `ga:transactionsPerUser` and `ga:cohortActiveUsers`. See the [Dimensions and metric explorer](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets) to see what dimensions can be queried together.